# How do I change underline for matching tags in Highlight Matching Tag extension for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I have installed "Highlight Matching Tags" extension to my Visual Studio Code editor and I want to change the color of the underline of the matching tags. Here is a link with info about the extension:

(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag)

About in the middle of the site I found this information:

highlight-matching-tag.styles   { opening: { name: { underline: 'yellow' } } }

This, I believe, is the code that will change the underline of matching tags, but what I dont know is how do I use this information? Where do I change the code?

Comment: It looks like that goes into your `settings.json` file.  So Gear Icon/Settings/-choose User or Workspace - then click on the `{}` on the upper right of the opened tabs bar and paste it in there.  You may have to reload vscode to see its effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to look for **settings.json** file, you can get it by following way:

```
File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Extensions -> Scroll down and find "Edit in settings.json"
```

There is already a JSON object there, just add the following pair in it

```
"highlight-matching-tag.styles": {
    "opening": {
      "name": {
        "underline": "blue" //write any color
      }
    }
  }
```

Finally, save it.

If you wanted to do this setting for a specific project then don't make changings in that global settings.js, just go to your root folder (project folder) and follow following steps:

- Create a folder named .vscode in the root folder
- Create a file named settings.json in that folder and add your
  settings there

[Reference for editing settings.json in VS Code](https://supunkavinda.blog/vscode-editing-settings-json)

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Shift+p** or **Cmd+Shift+p** . The command pallet will appear like this:[vs code command pallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dEik.png)

Type settings and click on "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"[vs code command pallet settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVUrx.png)

In the settings' JSON file, add a comma "," at the very last line and add the following code:

```
highlight-matching-tag.styles { opening: { name: { underline: "#155FFA" } } }
```

You can use hex code to choose your favorite color. Save the file.